# Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5 for developing a Blazor Server-side web app and I am encountering the below error:

```
Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform
A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. In a future version of Chrome, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.
1 source
blazor.server.js:1
```

Minimum code to reproduce this error: [myshop.zip](https://valstekt.com/assets/public_docs/shop/myshop.zip)

I haven't added any specific code about the navigator yet. How could I resolve this?

I see an error on the Blazor web app:

[image]

In the Chrome browser dev tools, I see:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a warning (from Chrome), not a direct error. Does your app function?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added the error images of the Blazor web app and the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Better set up a [mre] and state the versions of Blazor and Chrome. I don't have any such problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added a Minimum code to reproduce this error, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's the library that is using navigator features that Chrome is deprecating.

https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html

Here are some quotes of the blogpost:

> Beginning in M92, we plan to start sending deprecation notices for the navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform getters in the DevTools Issues tab.

> If your site, service, library or application relies on certain bits of information being present in the User Agent string such as Chrome minor version, OS version number, or Android device model, you will need to begin the migration to use the User Agent Client Hints API instead.

So you are not using the navigator getters in question,  but the library is, but it seems you can only wait for an update to the library's `.js` to make the warning go away.

Comment: I have added a Minimum code to reproduce this error, thank you.